# Create a UIImage from string data

Tags: ios, uiimage, base64

I am trying to populate an UIImageView with image data taken from a webservice.  Below is what I am trying to do and it does not populate the image at all.  The UIImageView is blank when my view loads.  This is in the viewDidLoad method.

```
imageData=@"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsK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\ne/7eP/SmWvSaACiiigAooooAKKKKAP";
NSString * temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/png;base64,%@",imageData];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:temp];
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *ret = [UIImage imageWithData:d];
[Photo setImage:ret];
```

Photo is a UIImageView.  Any suggestions to help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use a method as follows

```
- (UIImage *)decodeBase64ToImage:(NSString *)strEncodeData {
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:strEncodeData options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
return [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

}

And pass it my base64 string from the webservice call like this:

```
UIImage *image = [self decodeBase64ToImage:imageData];

[Photo setImage:image];
```